# How to implement Swipe action on listitem in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview and on swiping (either right or left) I want to provide intent. I searched and I got to know to use Gesture for this purpose but I did not get how I should use this with listview. Please somebody help me with the example (I am new to Android and I need complete explanation and similar example) Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a swipe to delete with animation @ http://graphics-geek.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2013-07-12T09:08:00-07:00&max-results=7. The blog is by Chet Hasse and you can use the same code for your purpose.

Comment: You can check this - http://software-workshop.eu/content/swiping-listview-elements